# Array value changes but there is no code that changes that value

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I need help to understand this.

```
var vectX = [];
var esaminatori = [];

... (code omitted)

vectX = ws.getRange(5, 10, 5, 3).getValues();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   if (vectX[i][0] != "") {
     numEsaminatori ++;
     esaminatori[numEsaminatori-1] = vectX[i];
   };
};

... (code omitted)

for (ii = 0; ii < 5; ii ++) {
  vectX[ii][3] = " ";
  for (i = 0; i < numEsaminatori; i ++) {
    if (vectX[ii][0] === esaminatori[i][0]) {
      vectX[ii][3] = esaminatori[i][3];
      i = 6;
    };
  };
};  

ws.getRange(5, 10, 5, 4).setValues(vectX);
```

The above lines are the only parts of a 230 lines program where appears the array vectX.

Array vectX comes from the spreadsheet and is an array of 5 rows 3 columns, rows may be full of empty, so I copy only the full lines to array esaminatori.
In the case I'm testing rows 3 and 5 are empty, rows 1, 2 and 4 have values. So in array esaminatori will be filled rows 0, 1, 2 while in vectX are filled rows 0, 1, 3 and rows 2 and 4 are empty.
During the program a new column (index 3) is inserted in array esaminatori, surprisingly the same value in column 3 is added in vectX, but no line of the code makes that. The most incredible is that the value is not inserted randomly, is inserted in the correct [row,column] having in consideration the empty lines.

At the end of the program I want to insert esaminatori column 3 in vectX to write it in the sheet, but not all the lines have values so I initialize the column 3 with a space, otherwise I'll get an error in writing.
Now, the strange is that the line that changes the value in vectX[ii][3] automatically changes the corresponding row in esaminatori and lose the content.

So, I could say that in some way the 2 arrays are connected and mirroring themselves.

I have a ghost in my program???

Comment: Can you share with us what your expected output should look like?

Comment: See  secrets of debugging in [mcve]. You may even find your , when trying the first step of "restarting from scratch"

Comment: @PatrickdC I expect that array vectX doesn't change, because in the script there is no code that modifies the data in it up to the last "for" loop.

Comment: In your script, I noticed that you are trying to append single spaces (" ") at the end of every row. Did you want to try and replace the blank indices of the array into single spaces and instead got this output instead? This is what I got from your script by the way: https://imgur.com/a/lOjQ3sQ

Comment: Arrays are assigned by reference not by value.  `esaminatori[numEsaminatori-1] = vectX[i]` assigns the address of the row array of `vectX` to `esaminatori` so now `vectX` and `esaminatori` share the same address.  No ghost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are assigned by reference not by value. esaminatori[numEsaminatori-1] = vectX[i] assigns the address of the row array of vectX to esaminatori so now vectX and esaminatori share the same address. No ghost.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
    let b = [];
    for( let i=0; i<a.length; i++ ) {
      b[i] = a[i];
    }
    console.log("b before:"+b);
    for( let i=0; i<b.length; i++ ) {
      b[i][0] = b[i][0]+10;
    }
    console.log("b after:"+b);
    console.log("a after:"+a);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

8:56:03 PM  Notice  Execution started
8:56:04 PM  Info    b before:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
8:56:04 PM  Info    b after:11,2,3,14,5,6,17,8,9
8:56:04 PM  Info    a after:11,2,3,14,5,6,17,8,9
8:56:04 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: @ TheWizEd now I understand, I didn't know that. Thank you so much. So  the contents of vectX is trustworthy and I can use it to write the info in the Spreadsheet. That's great and may be useful is certain cases.

Comment: If you could mark this as the answer it will help others with similar situation.  Thanks.